# use of select_related in this case of django rest?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, django-select-related

I have a situation where I am not sure whether I would be using select_related or not. I have a model like this:

```
class Example(models.Model): 

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)  
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True,
    related_name="user_example",
)
    /................./
```

Now in my view I have use filtering logic like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    
    search = self.request.query_params.get("search", None)

    if search_query is not None:
        queryset = Reactions.objects.filter(
            Q(user__name__icontains=search)
            | Q(user__email__icontains=search)                
        ).distinct()
```

Here Example model has a fk relation with User, so its a forward relation not a reverse relation. Should I be appeding `.select_related('user').filter(...)` in this above example to reduce the no of queries or there is no need here...I can't figure it out.

Serizalizer:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Reactions
        fields = ["id", "user", "title", "message"]
```

Comment: Can you share the serializer you are using? If you are accessing the related user in your serializer then yes you should use select_related, if not then it is not necessary

Comment: hello @IainShelvington i Have updated it with the serializer. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should. From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related):

> `select_related` works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the `SELECT` statement. For this reason, `select_related` gets the related objects in the same database query. However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from joining across a ‘many’ relationship, `select_related` is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python...

In your case we deal with a `ForeignKey`, so `select_related` is suitable. If you want to make sure that this decreases a number of DB queries, you can install [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) for that.

Comment: I have django-toolbar, but i am using postman for api calls because authentication is required for that api call. Now how can i use debug-toolbar in this case??

Comment: @Reactoo [`django-debug-toolbar-request-history`](https://github.com/djsutho/django-debug-toolbar-request-history) has to help you. You can temporarily disable the authentication if you are not sure if it hinders you.